# Scapy and tcp syn flooding attack

Tags: python, tcp, scapy

I'm trying to attack from a machine to another using a virtual environment.

When I initiated the attack, I can see that a connection stays in `SYN_RECV` mode. However, after a couple of seconds, it disappears.

I'm using this code:  https://github.com/EmreOvunc/Python-SYN-Flood-Attack-Tool/blob/master/SYN-Flood.py

How can I enable multiple `syn_recv`? Currently, only one connection is in syn_recv.

I have tried several methods:

- Making source IP static and different than both client's and server's IP. So that, at each iteration the IP address will also be changed.
- Only changing the last triplet of the client's IP address so that they will be in the same network.
- Completely create random IP.

I can see on the server's terminal, only one instance stays in the `SYN_RECV`. I have disabled `syn_cookies` in the server. I also didn't touch the default timeout value, which is 5 (3 minutes)

How can I make more than 1 connection at a time using scapy? Currently, I'm trying in an infinite loop trying to connect to the same server with known IP and Port number and a client changing source port and IP address at each iteration.